# JTextArea not visible

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jtextarea

Here is my code. I have tried to keep it very simple.

```
public class GUI_ADV extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass abc = new NewClass();
        abc.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        abc.setSize(250,450);
        abc.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        abc.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {
    public void NewClass() {
        JPanel cp = new JPanel();
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("text",5, 20);
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane( ta );  
        cp.add( jp );
        //message.setLineWrap(true);
        //message.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ta,5,5);
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //because it is done in main class
        cp.add(scroll);
        add(cp);
        //setVisible(true);    
        //Its done in main class
    } 
}
```

It is not working. It comes blank with the title bar and the empty window.

Comment: If you think I haven't tried a solution please let me know.

Comment: I have removed the irrelevant cruft from your question. Please take a minute to format your code properly.

Comment: what did you expect to get?

Comment: Sorry a line was missing.

Comment: You should really consider setting the layout in the component itself, before adding to it. The constraints to `add` depend on the layout, so setting it after may have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor should not be void or return any thing, else it will be considered like a method and not a constructor :

```
public void NewClass() {
//      ^^-------------------------mistake
```

Instead you have to use:

```
public NewClass() {
```